# How can I foreach all files in a dictionary?

Tags: php

I am working on a method of saving CPU by loading all my resources into ram before starting the my game server, rather then loading it into RAM on the fly.

So I save all my packet data in a dictionary. The files have random names. How can I foreach every file in the dictionary? I need something like this:

```
$path = //path to dictionary
foreach(//get dictionary files as $packet){
   $filename = //getfile name
   if(!isset($this->chunkCache[$filename])){
      $this->chunkCache[$filename] = $packet;
   }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out : `readdir()`

This bit of code should list all entries in a certain directory:

```
$path    = //path to dictionary

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

   while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

        echo "$entry\n";
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
```